# conflicting jQuery / Javascript with Galleria

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Basically, it is quite hard to explain but I have two Imageslider's that are using the same code? However the first one work's perfect, the second one is displaying a list of images, I figured this might be to do with a DIV ID? Or something that only allows you to use it once...

I am new to this and the problems can be found at this link:

www.steveatattooartist.com

Basically when you click 'sketchbook' the images are all over the place, but when you use Tattoo's they are all perfect.

I am using exactly the same code, why is that a problem? :?

Any help is help, or if you can't help direction usually is a big helping hand!

Comment: set up two different image sliders, that use different wrappers, and different data.... That's all I can suggest.

Comment: I'll give that a go :) WORKED! - Had to redo some javascript, but was the direction I needed! Thankyou very much!!

Comment: So... honestly, I thought you'd tried that, and I was just bein 'that guy'... lol. But I'm glad it spurred the right idea and put you on track.

Comment: Can I recommend that you don't edit anything live? I suggest setting up a sub-domain and doing your coding work there, and pushing it to a live state once everything is stable....

Comment: Oh, and think about minifying your JS with Uglify, on the fly builds so that you can reference a much smaller file.

Comment: I usually put up a holding page and build on a subdomain and transfer, but this is a very 'quicky' job so I am not putting the usual efforts in.. But thank you for the recommendation, Appreciate it!

Comment: @OwenO'niell Oh rad, and let me know if I can help any more.

Comment: You have done enough my friend! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

looks like the main problem you're going to have is lack of uniqueness in your id's.  change the `id="gallery"` to `class="gallery"` and change the javascript to look at `$('.gallery')`.

jQuery expects id uniqueness and will only select the first element with a given id.

Comment: Actually this will happen for any 'array' that a jQuery object returns as a matter of selectors. As soon as you try to do work on it, it shifts the first element, to what ever method is being chained. Every now and then with a class you can get away with it... but it's always better to do a '.each()' to ensure your code is doing what you want.

Comment: @Relic, while that is occasionally true, it doesn't matter here.  the id selector will always only return one element.